# difference between windows installer 3.1 and 4.5 While creating SetUP Project, which one to select when

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, installation, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am Creating SetUp Project for Win App. in VS2010 Framework 4.0

Now While selecting Prerequisites ( from Project properties win )

I have Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64) as per my project Requirement.

Now I am confused with Wind Installer which one to select

**(Windows Installer 3.1 / Windows Installer 4.5 )**

As are they Base on which OS the Application will be install or ....What ..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different OSes have different Windows Installer versions installed by default. See [Released Versions of Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371185.aspx).

If you plan to deploy your apps to **Windows XP or Windows 2003 Server**, choose Windows Installer **3.1**, and if you plan to deploy to **Vista or Windows 7** only, version **4.5** could be a better choice.

Comment: Following the link Alexey provided, you can see that some versions of Windows Installer are available as a redistributable package. So, you can consider adding 4.5 as a prerequisite to your setup bundle if you really need to rely on its features

Comment: Microsoft recommends using Windows Installer 4.5 on XP and newer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770(v=vs.85).aspx .